# Comparing two classifiers on separate pairs of train and test datasets

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In my problem I have 2 classifiers, C1 and C2. Both C1 and C2 are Naive Bayes classifiers but the difference between them is that they use different feature selection methods. Both classifiers are trained over a dataset of 10,000 instances (noisy-labeled), and tested over a different dataset of 1,000 instances (manually labeled), both datasets being balanced.

Now, I have plotted accuracy of both classifiers on increasing number of instances, and I found by visual inspection that C2 has generally better accuracy and recall than C1 . I would like to know whether such difference is statistically significant or not to assess that C2 is better than C1.

Previously, I used the same dataset for k-cross validation, got the mean and variation of the accuracies of both classifiers and computed student t-test on a specific amount of features. However, now I have 2 different datasets for training and testing. How could I perform a test in such situation? Should I get the mean of accuracies for all different feature amounts?

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

Regarding the domain, I am dealing with sentiment analysis (SA), classifying text data in 3 classes : positive, negative and neutral. 
Regarding error cost, at this stage I suppose that all error costs are the same (although I understand that the cost of classifying negative as positive would higher than negative as neutral). 
Regarding the "practical significant difference" when dealing with SA I am assuming that an improvement of 1% is significant, since previous papers usually present such kind of improvements. 
I want to test the accuracy of C1 and C2 when trained over automatic-labeled data, and tested over manually-labeled data.

Comment: Of course you mean that the classifiers are the same type and not the same.  Another way to compare classifiers would be by using the 632+ bootstrap.  You could use the bootstrap to test that error rate(s) for C2 is statistically significantly lower than for C1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both C1 and C2 are Naive Bayes classifiers but the difference between them is that they use different feature selection methods. So, should I leave the number of features static ?

Comment: @D.T. Different feature selection methods often lead to different selections of feature.  Usually the reason is that some features are related and the specific slection makes little difference.  In this case I think you should check to see if the difference between the error rates is statistically significant.  If it is then there may be a particular feature or features used for C2 but not C1 that is (are) imprtant to include.

Comment: Thanks again. 2 final questions: 1) 632 bootstrap samples with replacement to build a training set, leaving the rest of the data as test data. However, in my case, I have 2 different datasets for training and testing, and I can't use training instances for testing because training instances are noisy-labeled. How could I apply 632B to my problem then ? Sampling from each dataset ? 2) when using feature selection only the top k scores are selected. Should I fix such k when doing bootstrapping? Or average for different k's ?

Comment: @D.T. 1) The bootstrap samples with replacement from the full data set to estimate properties of the estimate (in this case the error rates). If does not build a training set.All you do to apply it is to use all the data for fitting and then take that data to bootstrap and repeat the fitting for bootstrap data sets. Then it uses the results to do a bias adjustment of the resubstitution estimate of error rate. I see no problem with applying it. You would just change the way you do the estimation.

Comment: As far as comparing the algorithms C1 and C2 is concerned you can do a different form of bootstrapping which bootstraps the process of generating the classifiers.  In this case you would take the training set and make it the data set for bootstrapping.  Generate bootstrap samples from the training data.  Use your algorithm for picking features and constructing the classifieers.  Then use the reserved data set to test the algorithm and calculate the error rates. Repeat this process many times.

Comment: It then allows you to see how much the selection of features and the construction of algorithms can change for one sample to the next.

Comment: Regarding 2) use the same value of k that you used in the original selection procedure when applying it to the bootstrap samples..

Comment: Thanks Michael! I will do what you say, bootstrap a random sample set from the whole training dataset, test over the whole dedicated test set, get test error and repeat. By the way, just a curiosity, would it be the same if I calculate accuracies instead of test error rates ?

Comment: If by accuracy you mean 1-error rate then sure it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Just a last question about evaluation, wouldn't it be more reliable to train classifiers on random subsamples without repeats of the training dataset, instead of bootstrapped samples that may contain repeated instances?

Comment: @D.T. I don't think that there is any advantage to subsampling over bootstrap.  In terms of estimating classifier error rates the bootstrap is generally better than leave-one-out cross validation and I am sure the same would be the case with subsampling.

Comment: @MichaelChernick In every iteration of bootstrapping, the two classifiers are trained with the same bootstrapped sample. However, in every iteration, should the two classifiers be tested over the whole separated test set, or over randomly sampled test instances? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, before testing you need to define couple of things: do all classification errors have same "cost"? Then you chose a single measurement parameter. I usually chose [MCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) for binary data and [Cohen's kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) for k-category classification. Next it is very important to define what is the minimal difference that is significant in your domain? When I say "significant" I don't mean statistically significant (i.e. p<1e-9), but practically significant. Most of the time improvement of 0.01% in classification accuracy means nothing, event if it has nice p-value.

Now you can start comparing the methods. What are you testing? Is it the predictor sets, model building process or the final classifiers. In the first two cases I would generate many bootstrap models using the training set data and test them on bootstrap samples from the testing set data. In the last case I would use the final models to predict bootstrap samples from the testing set data. If you have a reliable way to estimate noise in the data parameters (predictors),  you may also add this to both training and testing data. The end result will be two histograms of the measurement values, one for each classifier. You may now test these histograms for mean value, dispersion, etc.

Two last notes: (1) I'm not aware of a way to account for model complexity when dealing with classifiers. As a result better apparent performance may be a result of overfitting. (2) Having two separate data sets is a good thing, but as I understand from your question, you used both sets for many times, which means that the testing set information "leaks" into your models. Make sure you have another, validation data set that will be used only once when you have made all the decisions.

### Clarifications following notes

In your notes you said that "previous papers usually present such kind [i.e. 1%] of improvements". I'm not familiar with this field, but the fact that people publish 1% improvement in papers does not mean this improvement is significant :-)

Regarding t-test, I think it would be a good choice, provided that the data is normally distributed or converted to normal distribution or that you have enough data samples, which you will most probably will.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the domain, I am dealing with sentiment analysis (SA), classifying text data in 3 classes : positive, negative and neutral. Regarding error cost, at this stage I suppose that all error costs are the same (although I understand that the cost of classifying negative as positive would higher than negative as neutral). Regarding the "practical significant difference" when dealing with SA I am assuming that an improvement of 1% is significant, since previous papers usually present such kind of improvements. I want to test the accuracy of C1 and C2 when trained over...

Comment: ..automatic-labeled data, and tested over manually-labeled data. I would bootstrap models from sampled training set data and test them over samples testing set data, calculate mean and stdev of the test error. Now , would student t-test be ok for checking statistical significance? And, should I limit the amount of features to check to a certain amount or try for different amount of features?